# Trying to print out 400 results

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, sorting

```
for key, val in values.items():
if (val == sorted(values.values())[0]) or (val == sorted(values.values())[1]) 
or (val == sorted(values.values())[2]) or (val == sorted(values.values())[3]): 
    print key, '\n'
```

This code snippet prints the first 4 results of my code sorted. My thing has 400 results how would I write the code so that I don't have to copy and paste it 400times and still be sorted?

Comment: Try to understand what your code does and the solution should become obvious: sort the values and then loop on them to print them.

Comment: idk when I do it they arent sorted anymore

Answer (score 0):

you code is equivalent to:

```
if val in values.values(): print key, '/n'
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here.. by definition val is in values.values().
if you want to print sorted values you can:

```
sorted_list = sorted(values.values())
for item in sorted_list:
    print item, '/n'
```